# EC2 classic resource that can't be deleted - now what?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So, I wasn't aware of my using any ec2 classic resources, but since ec2-classic is being retired by AWS, it was suggested to use https://github.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder to find any ec2 classic resources that I may unknowingly have.

The script completes with the following message:

> Search for EC2-Classic Resources is complete! Please check for the CSVs output to this directory.If no resources were found in EC2-Classic for a service, empty CSVs were created with no resources except for Classic_Platform_Status.csv which shows the current status of all regions.As a final step once you have verified you have no other EC2-Classic resources, please open a support case and request your account be converted to VPC-Only as outlined in this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate.html

Most of the CSVs are empty, except for Classic_Platform_Status.csv and Classic_SGs.csv ; so I found that Classic_SGs.csv contains a solitary security group named "default" in us-east-1, whereas I have no other resources in that region.
[image: solitary resource]

And here's another look at what I have in this region from ec2's Region Explorer
[image: titles]
[image: No other resources]

Yet, when I try to delete that "default" security group, I get an error (screenshot with the actual ID after "sg-" hidden)
[image: the error]

Any idea why there is such an EC2-classic security group in us-east-1, and do I need to do anything about it?

Comment: It's a default security group, probably created when you initially signed up for AWS. If it isn't assigned to any resources then you definitely don't need to worry about it. The only EC2-Classic thing you need to worry about are actual EC2 instances, which it appears you do not have.

Comment: Can you plaese add a screenshot of the UI? What is reason in red? This is confusing me as the only plausible way you would get that message using that script would mean that the SG is still associated with a running **instance**, **network interface** or referenced by another **security group**. It only gets SGs that are not associated with a VPC. If the above are false, there's a bug somewhere in the script or the console.

Comment: Thanks, out of those possible reasons, the "Reason" picks out that it is a default security group. If this doesn't have to be, and cannot be, deleted, perhaps the script should not be including it in Classic_SG.csv?

Comment: Do you have the default VPC in the region? If so, you can ignore or by deleting hte VPC through the console it should be deleted. The SG will be deleted if you delete the default VPC

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - deleting a VPC will not delete an EC2-Classic SG (because it doesn't exist inside a VPC)

Comment: Deleting the default VPC will delete the default SG if it is assigned to one

Comment: I have no other resource in that region, no VPC, nothing, except for that SG.

Comment: Agree, you might want to raise this as an issue at [aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder](https://github.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder/issues).

Comment: @jarmod thanks, I just did